# How to run panels one after another in a same frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In my application, I have a main frame that holds a base panel. The base panel will hold 4 sub-panels. So lets say, the first sub panel appears, do a process on a data, then it must let the second sub panel to appear and also pass the result data to it. The the second sub panel must do another calculation and pass it to third one and so on.
I used card Layout for this, but I do not know how to make panels visible one after end of the previous panel's work.

Here is a simplified version:

```
public class LittleCardLayout{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LittleCardLayout();
    }
    public LittleCardLayout(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new BasePane());
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Base Panel:**

```
public class BasePane extends JPanel{
    public BasePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
            JPanel mainView = new JPanel(cl);

            mainView.add(new JPanel(), "empty");
            mainView.add(new TopPanel(), "toppanel");

            cl.show(mainView, "toppanel");
            add(mainView, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

**Sub Panel 1:**

```
public class TopPanel extends JPanel {
    int myValue = 23;
    int newVal;

    public TopPanel(){
         JButton btn = new JButton("Load Value");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               newVal= 23-3;

               add(new BottomPanel(newVal), "toppanel");
            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

**Sub Panel 2:**

```
public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {
    int num;
    JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();

    BottomPanel(int num){
        this.num = num;
        num = num*5;

        myLabel.setText(Integer.toString(num));
        add(myLabel);


    }
}
```

it must work like a step by step process.
So any idea to pass data from one panel to another and make them visible after one another? 
Also is it the right way to make such a step by step process, or there is a better idea?

Comment: @Aify it passes the data but does not make the second panel visible.

Answer (score 2):

As each panel completes it's processing, it should send a notification back to the parent panel, telling it that it has finished.  The parent panel would then decide what to do.

The child panel should NEVER make navigation decisions...

This is pretty basic example of the concept.

It uses two `interfaces` (I'm a stickler for coding to interface and limiting exposure of implementation details), a `Processor` which processes stuff and a `ProcessListener` which is used to notify the registered listener that the `Processor` has finished.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new BasePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class BasePane extends JPanel {

        private List<Processor> order;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;
        private ProcessListener processListener;

        public BasePane() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            order = new ArrayList<>(4);

            processListener = new ProcessListener() {
                @Override
                public void processingComplete(Processor source) {
                    int nextIndex = order.indexOf(source) + 1;
                    System.out.println(nextIndex);
                    if (nextIndex < order.size()) {
                        Processor next = order.get(nextIndex);
                        System.out.println(next.getName());
                        cardLayout.show(BasePane.this, next.getName());
                        next.startProcessing();
                    }
                }
            };

            createProcessor("Meaning of life");
            createProcessor("Apple Pi");
            createProcessor("Thermal dynamics");
            createProcessor("Microsoft Word");

            Processor first = order.get(0);
            cardLayout.show(BasePane.this, first.getName());
            first.startProcessing();
        }

        protected Processor createProcessor(String name) {
            ProcessorPane pane = new ProcessorPane(name);
            pane.setProcessListener(processListener);
            add(pane, name);
            order.add(pane);
            return pane;
        }

    }

    public interface Processor {
        public void setProcessListener(ProcessListener listener);
        public ProcessListener getProcessListener();
        public void startProcessing();
        public String getName();
    }

    public interface ProcessListener {
        public void processingComplete(Processor source);
    }

    public class ProcessorPane extends JPanel implements Processor {

        private ProcessListener listener;

        public ProcessorPane(String name) {
            setName(name);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel(name));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void setProcessListener(ProcessListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void startProcessing() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getProcessListener().processingComplete(ProcessorPane.this);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public ProcessListener getProcessListener() {
            return listener;
        }

    }

}
```

The basic concept could be expanded so that `Processor` had a `getValue` and `setValue` (for example) methods which would allow the controller (in this case the `BasePane`) to pass information from one `Processor` to another

This is just the implementation based on your current approach.  I might be possible to use a different approach which separated the UI from the processing, so that you had a "processing controller" which was controlling the processing work flow and passing notifications back to the UI (or registered listeners) about it's current state of operations.

Equally, you could use the above idea, but instead use polling, periodically requesting information from the "processing controller"...just as some ideas of the top of the head

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking. I thought maybe there is a way that second panel waits for the first's notification, then it takes its data and starts processing it. However I have no idea how it can happen. Threads? maybe?

Comment: Well, technically, when you get the results from the first, you could simply pass then to the next panel, which could then process it further...

Comment: Alright, so you mean the base pane must show all panels one after another, and each one passes values to another? And also how can I bring back to value from first sub panel to base pane in order to give it to the second sub panel?